# Web Setup Wizard Error

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, magento2.1.6, setup-upgrade, web-setup-wizard

In the admin panel, the normal Web Setup Wizard page is not showing. But there is no error in the front end. What might be the cause of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are encountering this [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159) - Web Setup Wizard not available when site is installed in pub folder.

Comment: It seems that there is no fix yet?

Comment: Nothing official but you can try some of the workarounds posted in that report which seem to work for some.